# Convert VB6 to VB2010 code

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Good Day, Please help me to convert the code below (VB6) to VB 2010,

```
Dim strconn As String
Dim condtl() As String

Open "c:\databaseSetting\dbsettings.dat" For Input As #1
Line Input #1, strconn
Close #1

strconn = Replace(strconn, """", "")
condtl = Split(strconn, ",")

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;data source=" & condtl(0) & ";initial catalog=" & condtl(1) & ";user id=" & condtl(2) & ";password=" & condtl(3)
cn.Open
```

---

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a code conversion service

Comment: MSDN has oodles of tips and articles on making the move from VB6 to VB.NET.  See also: [Ask]  this question shows no effprt

Answer (score 2):

Rather than convert code for you, I'll give you some pointers:

To open a file and read the lines:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (simpler if the file is small)

For string substitution you can use the string function 'Replace':

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And for a like-for-like database operation (i.e. opening an ADODB.Connection) you can learn here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308047